# Hierarchical Clustering customized Linkage function

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering

In my clustering project, I need to customize the linkage function, so that after each cluster merging I can update the inter-cluster distance in my own way.

Currently I'm using scikit-learn AgglomerativeClustering, which seems not having this customizable feature. After a quick glance in scipy, no luck there either. Does anyone know any python hierarchical clustering toolkit that has customizable linkage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fork sklearn and implement it yourself! The linkage function is referenced in [cluster/hierarchical.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py) as

> [join_func = linkage_choices[linkage]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py#L396)

and

> [coord_col = join_func(A[i], A[j], used_node, n_i, n_j)](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py#L520)

If you have time, [polish your code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#contributing-code) and submit a pull request when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Python, but ELKI allows customizing linkages easily.

I used this tutorial:

http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/HierarchicalClustering#Addingadditionallinkagestrategies

The Lance-Williams-Uodate approach is very efficient. But I don't think you can easily add Minimax Linkage the same way. It may be much more expensive to do minimax linkage?