# Customized function for Agglomerative Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, clustering

I need to use a customized linkage function for my project. For this function, on every step I should calculate the objective containing

- similarity (distance) between subclusters to be merged
- distances between leaves and roots in terms of edges in the forest of subclusters.

Currently I'm using scikit-learn AgglomerativeClustering. I looked through a [question related to mine](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11304/hierarchical-clustering-customized-linkage-function).

I found that the merging operation for max link and average link happens in [the script](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765acfa4c5d1ec05fc4b406968ad233c75162/sklearn/cluster/_hierarchical.pyx).

However, I cannot find where the the distances between all the subclusters are calculated and how to derive a number of edges between leaves and roots in subclusters.

How can this be done?

UPD: I am trying to implement [Chakrabarti](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.2915&rep=rep1&type=pdf) algorithms for smooth clustering over time. For agglomerative clustering, a choice for next clusters to be merged depends on two components: similarity between subclusters at current time stamp and a historical cost related to the previous time stamp. The latter has several variations. For example, one includes merge distance (not only that): if we would merge two subclusters S1 and S2, what would be the average distance (in terms of edges) between all leaves in S1 and S2.

There are a couple of questions about sklearn AgglomerativeClustering:

1. What lines in the code implement a choice of clusters to be merged at the current step?
2. Is it possible to extract a distance between a leaf and a root of a subcluster at each merging step? I noticed there is an attribute 'children_' in [AgglomerativeClustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) which I could use to create the resulting tree and find distances between any nodes. How to extract such an information for every merging step?

Answer (score 1):

Most implementations will begin with a distance matrix (and not a data matrix) as input, as the algorithms are O(n²) anyway.

For the second question, I don't understand how that is defined. If your linkage is not a Lance Williams update, you may need to reimplement hierarchical clustering completely, to make sure you have all the information you need. Lance Williams are much more elegant to compute.

Comment: Thank you, @Anony-Mousse!

I updated my questions with deeper explanations.

Comment: For this use case, I strongly suggest to implement it yourself, rather than hacking around the existing code limitations.

Comment: Thank you! Seems this is the best way for me to proceed.